# Attribute input value for another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

Fiddle updated: I didn't explain it very well, so I will explain what I am trying to do.
I am NOT trying to get form validation, I already have validation via the HTML 5 "required" field. 
What I want to do is be able to control the styles of ".error" which is populated by jQuery validate when a user fails to enter in a field or gives invalid information. How can I control the style is is not being populate by the jQuery validate function?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/140/

```
    $('#contactForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
            }
            postal_code: {
                required: true,
            },
            phone_primary: {
                required: true,
            }
            email: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="https://app.leadconduit.com/v2/PostLeadAction">
      <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" minlength="5" maxlength="255" placeholder="First Name" required />
      <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" minlength="2" maxlength="255" placeholder="Last Name" required />
      <input type="hidden" id="state" name="state" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" minlength="5" maxlength="10" placeholder="Zip Code" required />
      <input type="text" id="phone_primary" name="phone_primary" minlength="11" maxlength="12" placeholder="Phone" required />
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" minlength="25" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email" required />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a `div` in your code....

Comment: In your fiddle `error {}` in css, there is no error element

Comment: Read the note about placeholders on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You code has a syntax error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and the validation that is happening is html5 validation.

```
last_name: {
    required: true,
}    <----------------- no comma ----
postal_code: {
    required: true,
},
```